# How to eliminate values from list2 (which are common with another list1) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input:

```
list1 = ['name', 'age', 'gender', 'location']
list2 = ['name', 'age']
list3
```

Output:

```
list3 = ['gender', 'location']
```

How do I subtract common elements from list?

Comment: you can do this ```list3 = list(set(list1)^set(list2))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way could be to iterate over the larger of the 2 lists, and if the current element is not found within the other list, append to the end result.

**Example**

```
list1 = ['name', 'age', 'gender', 'location']
list2 = ['name', 'age']
res = []
for l in list1:
    if l not in list2:
        res.append(l)
print res
```

> **Output:** ["gender", "location"]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Use `list comprehension`,

```
In [4]: list3 = [i for i in list1+list2 if i not in list2]

In [5]: list3
Out[5]: ['gender', 'location']
```

OR

```
In [23]:  [i for i in list1+list2 if (list1+list2).count(i) == 1]
Out[23]: ['gender', 'location']
```

Comment: what if `list2` has more elements than `list1` and some of them are not in `list1`? It will not work in that case

Answer (score 1):

Use sets,

```
list3 = list(set(list1)^set(list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple method for beginers:

```
list1 = some_list
list2 = some_other_list
list3 = []
if len(list1) >= len(list2):
    longer_list = list1
    shorter_list = list2
else:
    longer_list = list2
    shorterlist = list1

for element in longer_list:
    if element not in shorter_list:
        list3.append(element)
```

This way, you account capture the entire difference. If the list in the outer loop is shorter than the list in the inner loop, you will miss some elements.

As you advance, you will pick up other methods like set difference: `list(set(list1) - set(list2))`, list comprehensions: `[i for i in list1 if i not in list2]`, filters with lambdas, etc.

Start with the basics, understand what's going on, befor learning fancy methods

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following code.

```
In [1]: list1 = ['name', 'age', 'gender', 'location']

In [2]: list2 = ['name', 'age']

In [3]: list3 = list(set(list1) - set(list2))

In [4]: list3
Out[4]: ['gender', 'location']
```

This method is similar to @Aidan Dowling answer that is by using [sets](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set). I think this would be better than using for loops.